# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_DOUBLE_ARROW in template.php

Tags: drupal-7

In Drupal7 theme Getting Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_DOUBLE_ARROW in /sites/all/themes/arizona_horizontal/template.php on line 254

```
    function template_node_submitted(&$variables){
return t('By !username on @datetime',
array('!username' => theme('username', $variables['node'], '@datetime' => format_date($variable['node']->created),));
```

}

Could you please tell me where exactly I am going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The second double arrow (`'@datetime' =>`) must be in `array()`. I don't know what you are trying to do but I guess you wanted to write that:

```
function template_node_submitted(&$variables){
  return t('By !username on @datetime', array(
      '!username' => theme('username', $variables['node']),
      '@datetime' => format_date($variable['node']->created),
  ));
}
```

You should probably consider formatting your code with better indentation, that would allow you to see this kind of syntax errors quickly.